# Python and Ansible IP Range to hostvars

Tags: python, ansible, ip

I'm trying to parse the following ip format into a inventory file in ansible. I'm looking for a custom python or available ansible solution.

User Input [might be a lot longer in some use cases]:

```
10.9.1.1-10.9.1.12, 10.9.1.15
```

Desired Output:

```
10.9.1.1
10.9.1.2
10.9.1.3
10.9.1.4
10.9.1.5
10.9.1.6
10.9.1.7
10.9.1.8
10.9.1.9
10.9.1.10
10.9.1.11
10.9.1.12
10.9.1.15
```

It would be ideal if ansible could accept an ip range for hostvars in the format of 10.9.1.1-10.9.1.12, but it seems like I'll need to make a custom module to make it into the 10.9.1.[1:12] format, or print it all out as above.

I'm using the same format to make API calls from the user input, which is why I don't want the user to input in a different format. After the API calls are made, I am going to run a script on each of these ips to install some software.

Progress [needs to be more dynamic though]:

```py
def ipRange(start_ip, end_ip):
   start = list(map(int, start_ip.split(".")))
   end = list(map(int, end_ip.split(".")))
   temp = start
   ip_range = []

   ip_range.append(start_ip)
   while temp != end:
      start[3] += 1
      for i in (3, 2, 1):
         if temp[i] == 256:
            temp[i] = 0
            temp[i-1] += 1
      ip_range.append(".".join(map(str, temp)))    

   return ip_range


# sample usage 
ip_input = ("10.9.1.1-10.9.1.12")
ip_input_start = ip_input.split("-")[0]
ip_input_end = ip_input.split("-")[1]
ip_range = ipRange(ip_input_start, ip_input_end)
for ip in ip_range:
   print(ip)
```

Comment: Hello Jesse, I think dynamic inventories might help you https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html you can find the script ec2.py here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/stable-1.9/plugins/inventory/ec2.py

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll check it out. I think I figured this out for now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that someone else can use if they run across this issue. This prints out all the ips in the arraylist. It should be easy enough to use in Ansible now.

```py
def ipRange(start_ip, end_ip):
   start = list(map(int, start_ip.split(".")))
   end = list(map(int, end_ip.split(".")))
   temp = start
   ip_range = []

   ip_range.append(start_ip)
   while temp != end:
      start[3] += 1
      for i in (3, 2, 1):
         if temp[i] == 256:
            temp[i] = 0
            temp[i-1] += 1
      ip_range.append(".".join(map(str, temp)))    

   return ip_range


# sample usage 
ip_input = ['10.9.1.1-10.9.1.12', '10.9.1.21-10.9.1.28', '10.9.1.15', '10.9.1.18']
for i in range(len(ip_input)):
    if(ip_input[i].count('-')==0):
        print(ip_input[i])
    if(ip_input[i].count('-')==1):
      ip_input_start = ip_input[i].split('-')[0]
      ip_input_end = ip_input[i].split('-')[1]
      ip_range = ipRange(ip_input_start, ip_input_end)
      for ip in ip_range:
          print(ip)
```

Output:

```
10.9.1.1
10.9.1.2
10.9.1.3
10.9.1.4
10.9.1.5
10.9.1.6
10.9.1.7
10.9.1.8
10.9.1.9
10.9.1.10
10.9.1.11
10.9.1.12
10.9.1.21
10.9.1.22
10.9.1.23
10.9.1.24
10.9.1.25
10.9.1.26
10.9.1.27
10.9.1.28
10.9.1.15
10.9.1.18
```